# Add to m2m field on seperate model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Problem:

I have 3 models in 3 separate apps

School
Student
Classroom

```
class School(models.Model): 
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Students = models.ManyToManyField(Student) 


class Classroom(models.Model): 
    School = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

What I want:

When a new classroom is saved the students that are in that classroom instance are automatically added to the students many-to-many field of the school model.

Then in the school page template I want to display the students in order of the date they were added to the school model, I think this part needs a separate through model but just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

> When a new classroom is saved the students that are in that classroom instance are automatically added to the students many-to-many field of the school model.

There's no such behavior, I can suggest this:

Remove `School.Students`, then any time you need students of a specific school, you do something along the lines

```py
Students.objects.filter(classroom__School__Name="Hogwarts")
```

If you want to keep both (for whatever reason) you can create your custom functions that add items into both. Or you can create custom managers to modify default behavior.

> Then in the school page template I want to display the students in order of the date they were added to the school model - I think this part needs a separate through model but just can't get my head around it.

You're right, if you want to add any field to a many-to-many you need to define your custom model. Then you can create a many-to-many out of it with `through`  option.

Comment: Actually there's such behavior, a custom save method would do it, but there's no need as this is duplicating the data, see my answer for more info

Comment: Many-to-many changes won't go through custom save method, it's only for normal model fields. Anyway you can of course customize them somehow but you shouldn't modify default behaviors without a big reason :)

Comment: Mb, a signal should do I think

Comment: @GTEE You're welcome :) remember to upvote and accept answers you found helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to stick with some pep8 fixes

```
class School(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student) 

class Classroom(models.Model): 
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

Second, unless you've a reason to set `name.max_length` to 100, set it to 255.

```
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I'd also set a related name to make things easier

```
class Classroom(models.Model): 
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='classrooms')
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

Now, to your problem.

Your logic is saying that a school can have many students and a student can enroll in many schools (weird but I'll cope), a classroom can exist inside a school and a school can have multiple classrooms, a classroom HAS MANY STUDENTS. This is a key here, you don't need to save the students in the school itself, you can just use something like

```
class School(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student) 
    
    @property
    def students(self):
        # iterate the class room, return a QS with all students from them
        # there're operators for union, but I'm using the function itself
        qs = Student.objects.none()
        for classroom in self.classrooms: # related name in action
            qs = qs.union(classroom.students)

        return qs
```

I'll add a note, the behavior you want can be done in a signal # DON'T DO THING, JUST KNOW IT

[More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad it helped.